# Drupal 7 - is it okay to write php codes inside a template file?

Tags: drupal, module, themes

I am learning Drupal 7 for my new project.

Here is what I want to do

1. create a new content type called 'video'
2. create a new module called 'video'
3. make http://domain.com/video accessible.
4. when a user access /video, then execute a query that queries video rows from video table (created by 'video' content type'), then display queries with a custom template.

I have learned how to do #1 ~ #3, but I am a little bit confused with #4.

let's assume that my custom template's filename is 'video.tpl.php'

in the video.tpl.php, do I write php functions to query video rows?

I don't think that is a good practice. Instead, I want to write a module and call a function in the module when the video.tpl.php is loaded.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views)

Comment: // thank you for your input. As I am new to Drupal, I really want to know how things work internally. Do you know how to do it with your own module or code?

Comment: I guess not yet. but i'll study and put something on my blog so we can discuss it :)

Answer (score 2):

For 4, you first need to create a module, implement hook_menu(), define a menu item for 'videos' with a page callback. If you don't know how to do that, there are likely already a lot of questions about that). Inside the page callback, you need to do 3 things.

1. Load the nids, something like

   $nids = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'video' ORDER BY created DESC")->fetchCol();
2. Load the nodes.

   $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
3. Build them.

   return node_view_multiple($nodes);

But again, you should *only* do this if you want to learn the API. Views will all of this do for you, you just need to click it together.

Comment: // I really appreciate your answers today. I have learned a lot from you. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Views is definitely the way to go.  you could write a module, but it would be like re-inventing the wheel.  Learn Views and you will use it again and again....
tutorials:

[a views tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB4QtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z13ylwMhk4&rct=j&q=drupal7%20views%20tutorial&ei=La9-TbeWFsqOrQHgj_WGCQ&usg=AFQjCNFWhUQgoFPeAN2Jh2IgoOWvepNNhQ&sig2=5COCk1AhhPu0OZEL6C_xaA&cad=rja)

[Another views tutorial](http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video/drupal-7-intro-views-pt-1)

Comment: // um...I think I should listen to you and bluefoot. I will give a try! Thank you guys!